# UICollectionView delegate method "didSelectItemAtIndexPath" not called when UICollection view used in UITableviewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I used UICollectionView in my UITableviewCell, Everything is working fine still loading the collection view and display its cell, But after loading collection view, i unable to get "didSelectItemAtIndexPath" delegate method of collection view when tap on collection view cell.

My Table view having static cell and i put collection view in that cell

Also define the delegate and datasource on it

Here is my code, data source method called but delegate not called

```
#pragma mark - collectionView data source


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *imgDocCell = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    imgDocCell.image = self.imgFileToChart;
    cell.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    cell.layer.borderColor=commonThemeColor.CGColor;
    return cell;
}


#pragma mark - collectionView delegate

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);
}
```

Comment: Where is `collectionView data source` code added?

Comment: I think its taking tableview delegate method . Put breakpoint in tableview delegate method and check it

Comment: @Mr.Bista in my tableview controller

Comment: Just check it and if its taking tabelview delegate method then disable userinteraction for that cell then its working for collectionview delegate

Comment: @jecky: i will try it, thanks

Comment: @jecky: tableview delegate not called

Comment: I dont know how you give outlet of collection view in tableview cell. Use tag for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125560/discussion-between-jecky-and-rohit-sidpara).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Remove outlet of collectioview and delegate and datasource too, See [OUTPUT HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AWHR.png)

you should write your code like this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 1;   
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    // Here tableviewcell inside one collection view create with tag 10
    UICollectionView *coll =(UICollectionView*)[cell viewWithTag:10];
    coll.delegate = self;
    coll.dataSource = self;

    return cell;
}
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}

// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell1 = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // in collectionview storyboard one UIImageview with tag 20
    UIImageView *imgDocCell = (UIImageView *)[cell1 viewWithTag:20];
    imgDocCell.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"add.jpeg"];

    return cell1;
}

#pragma mark - collectionView delegate

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);
}
```

Comment: Who give this post downvote? Please check code and if not proper then downvote it

Comment: You can't tell the user to copy-paste your code when you write something like `UICollectionView *coll =(UICollectionView*)[cell viewWithTag:10];`. What's it?

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti See bro Its common, Programmer must understand that I have to give my own tag here

Comment: I don't really think it's common. Instead I think it's wrong and error prone for the users who see your post

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti Yeah, its common , I give solution of it. Give outlet of anything that is in tableview cell , If you will get error or not just reply me

Comment: @jeckey: Thanks bro for your support, I achieved it by another way to creating button in collection view cell and take selector of it.

Comment: @rohitSidpara You can try this Also because I build demo for it and its working 100% . If you want demo I will give you

Comment: @jeckey: No bro because i will take static tableview and not implement the cellForRowAtIndexPath method in my code. I see your solution and it is perfect.

Comment: @rohitSidpara Ok, bro. You get your solution through me Great.

Comment: @Jecky: Please don't do this bro we all here for help each other not for fight or see something to some one else

Comment: @rohitSidpara Ok, bro. But I dont know Why people give downvote to certain right answer. That's why I comment on him